# On Android how to detect vibrator quality or vibrator type?

Tags: android, vibration, android-vibration, haptic-feedback

On Android, I can use `View.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.XXX)` to perform the vibration. But for older phones or phones with Eccentric Rotating Mass (ERM) haptic actuators (vibrators), the experience isn't great. So I want to detect and disable vibration on these devices.

But I haven't found any API to achieve this.

The closest API is `Vibrator.areEffectsSupported()`, but it always returns true on the devices I tested. In addition `Vibrator` and `VibratorManager` need `android.permission.VIBRATE` permission.

So, please tell me if you know.